# Adding Subquery Alias Results in: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, alias

When I run this query, it works:

```
select id1, count(*) from id_table
    where id2 = 'X' and id1 in
        (
       select numA from num_table where numB = 'Y' and numC like '%Z%'
        )
    group by id1
    order by count(*) desc;
```

However, when I run this one, I get the SQL command not properly ended error. Note that the ONLY difference is that I've given the subquery the alias 'sq1'.

```
select id1, count(*) from id_table
    where id2 = 'X' and id1 in
        (
       select numA from num_table where numB = 'Y' and numC like '%Z%'
        ) **sq1**
    group by id1
    order by count(*) desc;
```

I need to figure this out, because I'm trying to join to a subquery, and therefore need an alias for the 'on' clause.

Can someone explain why adding the subquery alias triggers this error?

Comment: you are trying to alias a list of values not a derived table or column

Comment: There's no join clause in your query

Comment: You can only define an alias for a derived table, not for a sub-query

Answer (score 0):

As I and others mentioned in comments the problem is that you are trying to alias something other than a derived table or column.

Think of your code like this:

```
WHRE id1 IN (SELECT numA FROM num_table) sql
```

is the same as saying:

```
WHERE id1 IN (1,2,3,4) sql
```

That doesn't look right, what would sql be aliasing?  the result of `id1 IN (1,2,3,4)` is basically a `boolean of true or false` it is not an object to be referenced in another part of the query.

You can actually alias the table if you wrote your query as a join.

```
select
    t.id1
    ,count(DISTINCT t.id1)
from
    id_table t
    INNER JOIN num_table sq1
    ON t.id1 = sq1.numA
    AND numB = 'Y'
    and numC like '%Z%'
where t.id2 = 'X'
group by id1
order by count(DISTINCT t.id1) desc;
```

Or as a derived table

```
select
    t.id1
    ,count(*)
from
    id_table t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numA
             FROM
                num_table
             WHERE
                numB = 'Y'
                and numC like '%Z%'
             ) sq1
    ON t.id1 = sq1.numA
where t.id2 = 'X'
group by id1
order by count(*) desc;
```

If id_table.id1 is unique both of these queries and the one you are attempting you OP will all give you ID, 1 as the answer.......

Comment: Matt, thank you. This is extremely helpful, especially thinking of it as an IN() clause. Really appreciate the patient answer.

Comment: @SethAKelley glad to be of help if my answer has satisfied your question if you could mark it as answered it would be great.  It lets others know that your issue has been resolved and awards reputation points.  Thanks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work